# Why it's showing Undefined index when I try to convert a module from M1 to M2?

Tags: magento2, module, error, code

I'm trying to convert one **module** to **M2**, and after running the **code_conversion_tool**, I've ended up with `.converted` files all around.

I've renamed them to replace the actual files.

While doing **setup:upgrade** I get:

```
[Exception]
  Notice: Undefined index: modules in <path to magento2>/vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php on line 47
```

If I remove the module from the app/code folder the error disappears, so it's clear that is the converted module causing this.

How can I pinpoint the origin of this issue?

I've done  " grep -rnisI "converter" * " inside the module folder and got 2 references for the word "Converter"

```
Model/Checkout/Onepage.php:30:
\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,

Model/Checkout/Onepage.php:59:         
$extensibleDataObjectConverter,
```

But i don't see any relation with **line 47** wich is:

```
$routeConfig['modules'] = $this->_sortModulesList($routeConfig['modules']);
```

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

This tool will not fully convert your module - it will only perform a limited set of code changes. You are responsible for remaining tasks.